# ruby connect.rb connects to Mongo but irb -r connect.rb fails

Tags: ruby, mongodb, ubuntu, rubygems

I'm learning Mongodb and ruby from the book "MongoDB in Action"
I have Mongodb installed ok and have managed to execute a number of commands on it.
I might not have ruby installed quite right.
I'm using Ubuntu 12.10 ruby 1.9.3

I have a program from the book called connect.rb

==========================================================

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'mongo'

@con = Mongo::Connection.new
@db = @con['tutorial']
@users = @db['users']
```

===========================================================

If I run the program using 
    ruby connect.rb

It runs without any error messages, however if I try to use irb I get the following error:

```
irb -r connect.rb
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p374/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in   `require':LoadError: cannot load such file -- connect.rb
```

I can type irb and get the irb prompt ok.

Answer (score 2):

It seems like irb cannot find that `connect.rb` file. You should runn it in an appropriate directory containing the file AND you should write the file path like this: `./connect.rb`
It has nothing to do with mongodb, as it doesn't even load your source file

look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13874115/why-does-irb-r-make-file-an-absolute-path) for futher info.